# Ambari 2.2 - exiting with non-zero status code on Ubuntu 14.04 Docker container

Tags: apache, hadoop, docker, ambari

TL;DR - Dockerized Ambari on Ubuntu 14.04 Docker container throws error upon startup with default configurations

I'm attempting to Dockerize an Ambari deployment to support running it along side my Hadoop containers. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV AMBARI_HOME /opt/ambari
ENV AMBARI_VERSION 2.2.0.0

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install wget software-properties-common python-software-properties openssh-client openssh-server

# Install Java.
RUN \
  echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

RUN mkdir -p "$AMBARI_HOME"
WORKDIR $AMBARI_HOME

# passwordless ssh
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && echo -e 'y\n'|ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N "" -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu14/2.x/updates/2.2.0.0/ambari.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ambari.list \
    && apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install ambari-server

#Disable SELinux
RUN echo SELINUX=disabled >> /etc/selinux/config

EXPOSE 8080

RUN ambari-server setup -s --verbose --java-home $JAVA_HOME
CMD ambari-server start
```

When I start the container I get the following error -

```
Using python  /usr/bin/python2
Starting ambari-server
Ambari Server running with administrator privileges.
About to start PostgreSQL
Organizing resource files at /var/lib/ambari-server/resources...
WARNING: setpgid(73, 0) failed - [Errno 13] Permission denied
Server PID at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid
Server out at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out
Server log at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log
Waiting for server start.........
ERROR: Exiting with exit code -1.
REASON: Ambari Server java process died with exitcode -1. Check /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out for more information.
```

There doesn't seem to be anything useful in the ambari-server.log or .out

I found an issue for `WARNING: setpgid(73, 0) failed - [Errno 13] Permission denied` fixed here: [setpgid issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-14466)

From reading the HortonWorks docs for deploying to Ubuntu 14.04, this should work:

[Install Ambari on Ubuntu 14.04](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_download_the_ambari_repo_ubuntu14.html)

I've tried to deploy with the embedded Postges as well as an external one with the same results.

One interesting note is that even with the error, Ambari appears to be up and I can login as the default admin/admin, but when calling `ambari-server stop' it says no process is running...

```
root@3e6d778b43f8:/opt/ambari# ambari-server stop
Using python  /usr/bin/python2
Stopping ambari-server
Ambari Server is not running
root@3e6d778b43f8:/opt/ambari# jps
868 AmbariServer
955 Jps
```

I'll replicate this setup on my Ubuntu box tomorrow and see if the same thing happens.

Thanks!

Edit #1: `docker info`

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/scripts$ docker info
Containers: 14
Images: 161
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 189
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-44-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.861 GiB
Name: vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
ID: 7AD6:Z5TH:76NW:G54B:IHVK:PWKP:E2LI:CRPI:MIGM:STJU:3D2B:K7EQ
WARNING: No swap limit support

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/scripts$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

docker is running inside of a Vagrant Virtualbox instance (v1.8.1)

Comment: I also went to version 2.1.2.1 -the pid warning went away, but a non-zero code was still raised.

Comment: can you add the output of `docker version` and `docker info`? Are you using the `overlay` storage driver?

Comment: Oh, probably not related.. I just saw the link to the setpgid issue

Comment: Here's the script I use to install docker and docker-compose on the host machine (its also Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for consistency):

Comment: #!/bin/bash

echo "Installing Docker..."
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
docker run hello-world
groupadd docker
gpasswd -a vagrant docker
service docker restart
newgrp docker
echo "Installing Docker-Compose..."
apt-get -y install python-pip
pip install docker-compose

Comment: No good suggestions here, but I have absolutely no experience with Ambari (reading this, I'm not a big fan of putting so much in a single container, but that's just personal preference). There *is* a known issue with `aufs` and certain kernel versions, which causes (JAVA) processes to deadlock. There's a patch for that, but it's not yet merge into upstream Ubuntu kernels; https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180. However, I think that issue is on newer kernels (your kernel, and ubuntu look to be out of date btw)

Comment: Is it not conventional to load a java webapp in a single docker container? all thats in this file is a java 8 install and the ambari binary. How could it be better 'dockerized'?

Comment: Well, it possibly the way Ambari is developed, but, for example, I saw an `openssh-server` installed in the dockerfile, in addition to the embedded postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem with ambari-server inside docker on ubuntu 14.04. Could you try the following

### Workaround the aufs problem

Inside /etc/default/docker add

`DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper"`

and restart the docker service. Note that after this all your images will disappear (http://muehe.org/posts/switching-docker-from-aufs-to-devicemapper/). Rebuild your images.

To be honest I'm not 100% sure if this part is really needed.

After switching from aufs to devicemapper you might get the following error:

[ERROR: Could not find container for entity id](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17691)

The solution was to remove the old AUFS db and any existing containers:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/linkgraph.db
```

Restarting your docker images/containers should now work on the devicemapper engine.

### Put apparmor into complain mode for docker

Inside `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` comment out (#) line `deny @{PROC}/{*,**^[0-9*],sys/kernel/shm*} wkx,`, it somehow confuses apparmor utils. Than run

`sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/docker`

If aa-complain throws command not found, install:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

After starting the container ambari-server started working for me.

I dont know how docker relies here on apparmor, i.e. what risks the operation above introduces...

Comment: Can I use the docker file above or Horton works? Which image did you use?

Comment: I have started with a bare ubuntu docker image, configured ssh server to run in it and tried to install hortonworks by hand (ie inside ssh session, two separate master and slave containers). I haven't  tried your docker file (just stumbled at the exactly same problem as you did)

Comment: I forked hortonworks Ambari ambari-server image: https://github.com/mikeblum/docker-ambari

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an issue deploying Ambari to a docker container.. I broke it out and installed it onto a Vagrant 14.04 Ubuntu VM wit the following scripts:

**install_java.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
```

**install_ambari.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu14/2.x/updates/2.2.0.0/ambari.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ambari.list \
    && apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install ambari-server
```

Followed by:

`sudo ambari-server setup -s -v -j $JAVA_HOME`

`sudo ambari-server start -v`

@thaJeztah - what do I need to fix with my Dockerfile setup?

Comment: alright I tried the dockerfile, and there's one thing I noticed; the `ambari-server` is a python script that starts the amberi server, then exits. Given that that script is the primary process of the container, the container is *stopped* once the `ambari-server start` command finishes; the server is running, but because the wrapper script is completed, the container stops. To solve this, you probably need to use the server itself as main process, or an init script (e.g. supervisord, tini)

Comment: That makes sense - like run CMD ['bash'] at the end of the Dockerfile? Is there a way (docker-style) to squench the -1 error coming from the ambari server startup so the container doesn't die?

Comment: I don't really know; I haven't checked what the *actual* server command is that the python script starts; you should check if that is able to run in the foreground, but that'll only work if it's the *only* process running. If you like being able to override the command, also have a look at, for example, the official MySQL image's entryoint script; https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/cf1bf4ff39736ebd78b6504007c470fd37616f4c/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L4-L9

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and forked Hortonworks Dockerfile for Ambari and can replicate the -1 errorcode/zombie Java process: https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-ambari/blob/master/ambari-server/Dockerfile I think its most likely related to the GitHub issue on zombie processes: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180. I'll try doing what mysql is doing here... I know nothing about CentOS...

Comment: ah, that may explain things; if you're using boot2docker, you can try the release-candidate; https://github.com/tianon/boot2docker-legacy/releases/tag/v1.10.0-rc1 which has the aufs patch applied. Otherwise switching to another graph-driver (such as overlay) can do the trick

Comment: I'm running on a virtual box ubuntu 14.04 VM.. is there a way to switch the engine to overlay when running on Ubuntu as the host OS?

Comment: hm, overlay requires a more recent kernel. Ubuntu 14.04.3 does use kernel 3.19, which should support overlay

Comment: Thank you.  I'll build a VM with 14.04.3 and give it a spin. I think I might just let ambari be installed without a container. It worked installing on the Ubuntu AWS image.  I can still keep the rest of the services in containers (ldap for example). I'm surprised my tomcat Docker image doesn't suffer from this problem.. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/tianon/boot2docker-legacy/releases/tag/v1.10.0-rc1, which already has the aufs patch applied and has a recent kernel (so also supports overlay)